# Matching two arrays and get the common values having proper key value match

Tags: php

I am using php and i have  two arrays, and i want the values that are common in two arrays, with same index like

> Array 1([0] = [Destnation] [1] = [Price] [2] = [Test])
>
> Array 2([1] = [Destnation] [0] = [Price] [2] = [Test])

So in the above arrays i want the output as

> Array 3([2] = [Test])

Because the other two values have changed there index

I have used array_intersect(), but it is giving all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/array_intersect_assoc)

It will compare keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++)
{
    if($array1[$i]==$array2[$i])
    {
        $result[] = $array1[$i];
    }
}
```